# What elementary matrices affect the following elementary row operations of a 4x4 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is in a review sheet without answers for my class, but I don't understand the question very well.

A) Exchange Row 2 and 4,
B) Row 1 +2(Row 3),
C) Multiply Row 3 by -2.

Am I just supposed to make a basic 4x4 and solve for the elementary matrix or is there a certain matrix that has problems with these operations?

Thanks.

Comment: More context is required.

Comment: You probably mean [*effect*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effect), rather than [*affect*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affect).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the question is asking for the elementary matrices that perform the specified action. For instance, if one wishes to exchange row 2 and row 4, then one multiplies on the left by the elementary matrix
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
To add twice row 3 to row 1, one multiplies on the left by the matrix
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Finally, to multiply row 3 by -2,
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: The matrices are obtained by performing the corresponding row operation on the identity matrix.